# python3.x list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

log：IndexError: list assignment index out of range

I can not fix.list assignment index out of range. Can you help me ?

---

```
  j=1
    n=int(input())
    flag=[]*29
    a=[]*29
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i]=1.0/(i+2)
    for j in range(2**29):
        temp=j
        index=0
        sum=0
        while temp>0 and index<29:
            flag[index]=temp%2
            index=index+1
            sum+=(temp%2)*a[index]
            temp=temp/2
    if sum==1:
        count=0
        index=index+1
        for i in range(index):
            if flag[i]==1:
                count+=1
        if count==n:
            for i in range(len(flag)):
                if flag[i]!=0:
                    print(flag[i]+"/"+(i+2)+"")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what this code is supposed to do, but I suggest you initialize your lists like this:

```
N = 29
flag = [None] * N
a = [1.0 / (i + 2) for i in range(N)]
```

If you just do `[] * 29`, the list is still empty, just like `29 * 0` is still `0`.

There seem to be more errors after that, but without knowing what the code is supposed to do it's impossible to suggest how to fix it.

Comment: sum+=(temp%2)*a[index]

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: N=29
j=1
n=int(input())
flag=[None]*N
a=[1.0/(i+2) for i in range(N)]

Comment: @xiaomak Yes, that one of those follow-up errors I was talking about that I can not help you with without knowing what the code is supposed to do.